# Passing multiple error messages through callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, callback

I am using [the got library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) to make some http requests. A typical `got` request looks like this:

```
got.post(url, options, function(err, body, res) {
  ...
}
```

The callback has errors as well as the body content and the full response. In some cases when connecting to certain 3rd party APIs, if I get an error response, I find both the `err` and `body` both contain important error information I would want to pass back up the chain of callbacks:

```
API.prototype.makeRequest = function(callback) {
  got.post(url, {}, function(err, body, res) {

    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return false;
    }

    // Otherwise do stuff

  });
}

// app.js    
var myAPI = new API();
myAPI.makeRequest(function(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }

  // Do stuff...
});
```

So in this example, I'm obviously only returning the error for the response. An example of this error:

```
{ [HTTPError: Response code 400 (Bad Request)]
  message: 'Response code 400 (Bad Request)',
  code: undefined,
  host: 'api.someservice.com',
  hostname: 'api.someservice.com',
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/oauth2/token_access',
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request' }
```

But if I examine the `body` of the error request, I see even more important and relevant error information:

```
{ error_description: 'Grant type is not supported: some_type_of_grant', error: 'unsupported_grant_type' }
```

So I have useful information in both the `err` and `body` variables that I want to pass back up the callback chain since both are useful.

What is the best approach to this? Typical Node.js approach seems to be having a single `err` value be the first value in the callback. Should I combine them into a single object or combine them and formulate my own error? Any other good approaches?

Comment: Combine into one error. ```cb({ headers: err, body: body })```. And pass them down the way like exception except you would need to manually transform if needed.